# How to set memory limit while running golang application in local system

Tags: go, goland

i want set heap size for go application in my windows machine

In java we used to provide -Xms settings as vm arguments in intellij but how to provide similar setting in golang and set memory limit for the go application.

Tried with

```
<env name="GOMEMLIMIT" value="2750MiB" />
```

but not working

we are using go 1.6.2 version.

Comment: which version of Go are you using?

Comment: we are using go 1.6.2 version

Comment: Go 1.6 is years outdated and doesn't know the new GOMEMLIMIT environment variable. You should upgrade to Go 1.19. Setting environment variables is pretty simple, you'll find information online for your system.

Comment: @NisargBhagavantanavar Hi, if for some reason you can't upgrade your version of Go, you can try using the OS to limit your application stack usage, such as [ulimit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ulimit.3.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Go 1.19 adds support for a soft memory limit:](https://go.dev/doc/go1.19)

> The runtime now includes support for a soft memory limit. This memory limit includes the Go heap and all other memory managed by the runtime, and excludes external memory sources such as mappings of the binary itself, memory managed in other languages, and memory held by the operating system on behalf of the Go program. This limit may be managed via [`runtime/debug.SetMemoryLimit`](https://go.dev/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetMemoryLimit) or the equivalent `GOMEMLIMIT` environment variable.

You can't set a hard limit as that would make your app malfunction if it would need more memory.

To set a soft limit from your app, simply use:

```
debug.SetMemoryLimit(2750 * 1 << 20) // 2750 MB
```

To set a soft limit outside of your app, use the `GOMEMLIMIT` env var, e.g.:

```
GOMEMLIMIT=2750MiB
```

But please note that doing so may make your app's performance worse as it may enforce more frequent garbage collection and return memory to OS more aggressively even if your app will need it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but we are currently using go 1.6.2 version, I don't think above setting works

Comment: @NisargBhagavantanavar Only the current and previous major versions are supported officially, currently Go 1.19 and Go 1.18. If you are truly using Go 1.6.2, I'd suggest to update to the current version immediately, as such an obsolete version has numerous unpatched security bugs. Go 1.6 was released in 2016!

Comment: `1 << 20 = 200000 * 2750 = 550000000` which is 524.520874023 mebibytes

Comment: @Leahcim `1 << 20 = 1048576`.